# ¿Cómo agrupar puntos en una figura siguiendo la distribución normal alrededor de tres centros?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algoritmos, matplotlib

Tengo un código que se utiliza para crear 100 puntos dibujados al azar basados en una distribución normal centrada en el punto (1, -2) con una desviación estándar de 0.3. Estos puntos se muestran a continuación.

```
points =  np.random.randn(100,2)*0.3 +[1,-2]
plt.scatter(points[:,0],points[:,1],c='r')
plt.show()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero crear tres grupos de 200 puntos dibujado al azar utilizando una distribución normal de 0.05 y centrado en los siguientes centros:

- 0,8 ; 0,3
- 0,3 ; 0,2
- 0,5 ; 0,9

**Cómo mostrar estos tres grupos en la misma figura con tres colores diferentes ?**

Los puntos generados a la pregunta anterior se guardarán en una sola variable `x`. Esta variable se corresponderá con los puntos de mi conjunto de aprendizaje del algoritmo K-means que quiero configurar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dices que quieres generar una lista `x` con los 300 puntos, pero que los quieres representar con colores separados.

Creo que la forma más simple es generarlos de forma separada, en tres arrays, y usar éstas para la representación gráfica. Después concatenar esos arrays para tener tu variable `x`.

Es decir, para la figura:

```
nubes = []
for centro in [(0.8, 0.3), (0.3, 0.2), (0.5, 0.9)]:
  nubes.append(np.random.randn(100,2)*0.3 + centro)

for i, nube in enumerate(nubes):
  plt.scatter(nube[:,0], nube[:, 1], label="Cluster {}".format(i))

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: Fig]

Y para ka `x` final:

```
x = np.concatenate(nubes)
```

`x.shape` es `(300,2)`

Answer (score 3):

Puedes configurar los parámetros de generación de los puntos en una lista, e iterar por esta para generar cada conjunto. Si no te preocupan los colores, con tal que sean diferentes, puedes generar una paleta para la cantidad de grupos que tengas, sino simplemente define el color dentro de la lista como un parámetro más:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import numpy as np

params = [
    [100, 0.3,  1, -2],
    [200, 0.5, .8, .3],
    [200, 0.5, .3, .2],
    [200, 0.5, .5, .9],
]

colors = cm.rainbow(np.linspace(0, 1, len(params)))
for i,(cant, sd, x, y) in enumerate(params):
    points =  np.random.randn(cant,2)*sd +[x, y]
    plt.scatter(points[:,0],points[:,1], c=colors[i], alpha=.5)

plt.show()
```

Te sugiero usar el parámetro `alpha` (transparecia) ya que hace más visible la concentración y solapamiento de los puntos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]